# Notion of distance in a Hypergraph

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces, hypergraphs

I've been trying to find canonical notions of distance in hypergraphs which generalize the notion of distance in graphs. I was hoping for a distance which also encodes a metric on two subsets of the vertex set. Are there some classical/cannonical such distances on hypergraphs?

I would be thankful for any useful idea on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct analogue of graph distance (at least that I can think of) is as follows.

If $u$ and $v$ are vertices of a hypergraph, and $e_1, e_2, \dots, e_k$ are hyper-edges, then we say that $P: e_1, e_2, \dots, e_k$ is a $u-v$ path of length $k$ if $u\in e_1$, $v\in e_k$, and for each consecutive pair $e_i$ and $e_{i+1}$ have at least one vertex in their intersection. In other words, a $u-v$ path is a sequence of edges, starting with one containing $u$, ending with an edge containing $v$, such that each consecutive pair of edges 'overlap'. (See the diagram for example)
Then we set the distance $d(u,v)$ to be the minimum length of a $u-v$ path.

[image]

Note that *any* metric between vertices you find can also be adapted to a pseudo-metric between subsets (you may get two different subsets with distance 0 between them, but nothing else goes wrong).

If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of vertices, then you get the 'induced' distance $d(A,B) = \min\{d(u,v) : u\in A, v\in B \}$.

Comment: Well, i would have expected something more similar to the hausdorf distance for subset (your pseudo distance is zero everytime the sets intesect which is probably too lossy). Anyway my 5 cents: for any distance $d$ on the vertex set i would define $d'(A, B) = \max( \max_{x \in A} d(x, B), \max_{y \in B} d(A, y) )$.

(note that this is the actual hausdorf distance adapted for compact spaces)

Comment: Coming here as a computer scientist: how would you best define a distance on a hypergraph, which takes into account the number of vertices in a hyperedge (ie, how many vertices need to be checked algorithmically to find the continuation of the path) into the distance's measure ? Ie, a path taking only $n$ "normal" edges (2-hyperedges) could potentially be shorter than one taking $m < n$ $k$-hyperedges, with $k > 2$

Comment: @TristanDuquesne You could add weights to the hyper-edges based on the vertex number. For example, if you want the edge length to directly correspond to the number of vertices to check, then if an edge had $k$ vertices in it, you would give it weight $k-1$ (and then the distance becomes the lowest total weight of a path). This particular choice of weight gives you exactly the normal graph distance if all your edges happen to be normal 2-edges.

Comment: Another issue with this definition is that it does not really see the hypergraph structure: if you replace any hyperedge by a clique on the same vertices, your hypergraph becomes a graph and your distance remains the same for any two vertices that do not belong to the same hyperedge/clique.